# find users local time through ajax call

Tags: javascript

Can I make an empty ajax call and then get the `getResponseHeader('Date')` to get the local time of the user?

```
function getServerDate(){
    var xhr = null;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
      xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{ // ie
      xhr = new ActiveObject("Microsoft")
    }

    xhr.open("GET","/",true);
    xhr.send(null);
    xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
        var time,date;
        if(xhr.readyState == 2){
            time = xhr.getResponseHeader("Date");
            date = new Date(time);
            console.log(date);
        }
    }
}
```

For `instance` if the `user` has changed his local time, to get the current local time.. can we make an empty get call and try to convert it like below:

```
var time = getServerDate();
var lcTime = new Date(getServerDate());
```

Comment: Did you try? what happened? Your code is using a asynchronous request and you are treating it as synchronous

Comment: @epascarello: https://jsfiddle.net/206u9yob/1/ here is something i tried, but not sure whether this is right or wrong.

Comment: @epascarello: Here is the right fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/yeftp7bj/

Comment: If the user has changed the time on their computer, why would the server know what the real time is? It makes no sense for the computer to report anything other than the time it know of when making an AJAX request (or anything else with time).